# Postcode limitations

Tags: civimail

We never had a problem with the postal code, nothing has changed, but this time CiviMAIL generates an error, caused by a limit on the postal code (between 2000 and 3000). Where is this limitation/validation set?

Drupal 7.61 CiviCRM 4.7.30 No extensions

> WHERE ROUND(address.postal_code) >= 2000
>    AND ROUND(address.postal_code) <= 2999
>    AND contact_a.is_deleted = 0
>    AND contact_a.id NOT IN (
>      SELECT contact_id FROM civicrm_group_contact
>      WHERE civicrm_group_contact.status = 'Removed'
>      AND   civicrm_group_contact.group_id = 72 ) );
>      [nativecode=1292 ** Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'NL-4651 JV']   [to_string]
>   => [db_error: message="DB Error: unknown error" code=-1 mode=callback
>   callback=CRM_Core_Error::exceptionHandler prefix=""
>   info="CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE civicrm_temp_group_contact_cache1878

Comment: I can not find the statement WHERE ROUND(address.postal_code) >= 2000 in any of the core code. What version of CiviCRM is this in and do you have any customizations or additional extensions?

Comment: You might also try applying https://github.com/cividesk/civicrm-core/commit/7df0c30e37a163bf59d22c3bc5b4397f57faaa95 and see if it fixes the error for you

Comment: @ErikH-CiviCooP Version added, no extension.